# Does file size affect how difficult it is to crack?

Tags: encryption, password-protection

Lets say I have a zip file of 50kb and a zip file of 100gb both encrypted using AES-256 using a password.

If someone wants to force their way into it would the size of the file affect how fast or slow it take to crack the password?

Comment: No. The size (and complexity) of the password is what makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends mainly on the methodology used to crack the password ( Brute Force, WordLists, Rainbow Tables .... ) and the strenght / complexity of the password.

Nothing to do with the file size.